# Salesforce to retry the 3rd party REST API

Tags: salesforce

I have few leads in my Salesforce and when I update a lead, I want to notify the change to a third party REST API end-point-address. If the response returned from end-point-address is incorrect or the third party API server is down, I want the Salesforce to retry notifying the end-point until a proper response is received. 
Can somebody please tell me, how can I configure Salesforce to retry the 3rd party REST API until a proper response is received?

Thank you,
Abhilash

Comment: Take a look at [Salesforce Integration Patterns](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.integration_patterns_and_practices.meta/integration_patterns_and_practices/integ_pat_intro_overview.htm), choose one and implement it

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends which tools do you want to use.
You can integrate 3rd party APIs for your declarative tools in SF using "External Services" tool. You can read and learn more about it here:
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/external-services

This simple solution will allow you to build flows and trigger external services for get and post methods.

In general, you wouldn't want to retry a notification to the end-point until a proper response is received, since it can cause an infinite action. It is better to receive and handle the response, according to the error message.

Comment: While External Services is the right idea (sort of), unfortunately the current implementation won't retry failed requests for you.